# Get value of textbox as a child of column of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a table, showing some details, In each row I am fetching value from database and I want to develop an web application through user can directly manipulate content of any row and click on update and that change should be updated.

Here is the code :

```
    var row = parseInt(id);
    var name = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[1];
    var type = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[3].innerHTML;
    var pass = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var load = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[4].innerHTML;
    var intercom = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[5].innerHTML;
    var f_id = document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[0].innerHTML;
```

And here is the table:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%" id="faculty">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Namet</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Load</th>
    <th>Intercom</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

    <%
    if (session.getAttribute("facultybean") == null) {
      response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
      ArrayList fb = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("facultybean");
      int count = fb.size();
      for (int i=0 ; i < count; i++) {
        FacultyBean fb1 = (FacultyBean)fb.get(i);
    %>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <%=f b1.getId()%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="<%= fb1.getName()  %>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="<%= fb1.getPass()%>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="<%= fb1.getType()%>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="<%= fb1.getLoad()%>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="<%= fb1.getIntercom()%>" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Update" id=" <%= fb1.getId()%> " onClick="update(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <% 
      }
    }
    %>
</table>
```

Suppose for row 1 & col 2 I have text field as `<input type="text" value="value1"/>`
and user changes value to abcd but my js code still returns `<input type="text" value="value1"/>` instead of `<input type="text" value="abcd"/>`

Comment: You are getting the innerHTML which doesn't change. What you want to do is getting the value of the input field. document.getElementById("faculty").rows[row].cells[0].value

Comment: @user2415266 I need to add <input type="text" id="faculty" value="abc"/> and then call above method?

Answer (score 0):

you can add keyup event for input

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
   var x=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
   $(this).attr('value',$(this).attr('value')+x);
});
```

Comment: What if I hit backspace?

Comment: it's just a tip..you can check bakspace keypress and code a function for it

Comment: @user3623491 will this work for particular column of particular row ?

Comment: no this is for all input:text elements...there are many ways for particular column of particular row..for example give a class name for that column of row or etc